# 'Bad Request - Error in query syntax' when calling Webservice method with long? parameter

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to call this method of my .svc file:

```
[WebGet]
public List<Request> GetRequestFilteredForUser(string login, long? minDate, short? statut, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

With this url:

http://localhost/Service/DataService.svc/GetRequestFilteredForUser?login='ADM'&minDate=634448160000000000&statut=5&pageIndex=1&pageSize=99

I get the exception: **Bad Request - Error in query syntax.**

If I call without the 'minDate' param, all work fine:

http://localhost/Service/DataService.svc/GetRequestFilteredForUser?login='ADM'&statut=5&pageIndex=1&pageSize=99

What is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long (or Int64) literal in URL needs to be in the format ###L, so for example 64L. So just add a trailing 'L' to your value and it should work. See this table for more details:
http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/overview#AbstractTypeSystem

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you helped me solve passing a Decimal value in the same way.   However your link is dead, here is the link where I found the information.  http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/ under "Primitive Data Types"